# How to fix scroll up in jquery?

Tags: jquery

let's assume i have a div element, with static height and width

```
<div style="height: 500px; width: 300px;" id="scrollable">
```

how can i fix the moment, when mouse scrolls up on this div?

is there something like

```
$("#scrollable").scrollup(function()
{
     console.log("scrolled");//???
});
```

Thanks

Update:

i'm sorry for not clearly asked question, but as mentioned in the comment,

i need a event that detects mouse **wheel** movement, up and down.is it possible?

Comment: The moment? Can you elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: Try .scroll() - http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: i need to fix scroll up event on div, which has not `overflow:scroll`

Comment: There is no 'scroll up' event.

Comment: Possible interpretations: 1) He needs a event that detects mouse wheel movement. 2) He needs to attach something the the `scroll` event. 2a) He needs to find the **time** when the event is triggered 3) He is having some sort of CSS layout problem where the scrollbar is appearing.

Comment: Exactly i needs a event that detects mouse wheel movement. i did't know the word **wheel** :D:D:D sorry:) so, is it possible?

Comment: Do you mind if the scrolling is caused by the mouse wheel, scroll bar or keyboard arrows?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var scrollTop = $("#scrollable").scrollTop();
$("#scrollable").scroll(function(){
    if(scrollTop>$(this).scrollTop()) { alert('hi'); }

    scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
});​
```

with this div:

```
<div style="height: 500px; width: 300px; background: #eee; overflow: auto;" id="scrollable"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>​
```

or try this here live: http://jsfiddle.net/St4fW/1/